# Read More link scrolling page

Tags: read-more

I'm creating a theme, and I want to prevent the page from being scrolled when a user clicks 'Read More' and the code given in [the Wordpress Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Customizing_the_Read_More#Prevent_Page_Scroll_When_Clicking_the_More_Link) is not helping me at all.

My `functions.php` is exactly the same as the snippet in the Codex and the relevant line of my `index.php` is:

`<div class="content"><p><?php the_content(__('Read More')); ?></p></div>`

Edit: I have a new, weird bug: the content of the Codex snippet is being shown as raw HTML in my blog and admin pages.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "scrolled"?

Comment: I mean that the link, when clicked, leads to a position some way down the page instead of at the top.

Comment: There is a theme or a plugin involved in this somehow. I assume it is loading Javascript or creating links with `#someid`. Without knowing the details there is no way to answer though.

Comment: I'm using the [WordPress Popular Posts](http://wordpress.org/plugins/wordpress-popular-posts/) and [WP-PageNavi](http://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-pagenavi/) plugins. No js in the theme itself, which I created from scratch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an explanation in the WordPress Codex which I copy here for reference.

**Don't forget `<?php` and `?>`**

```
<?php
function remove_more_link_scroll( $link ) {
    $link = preg_replace( '|#more-[0-9]+|', '', $link );
    return $link;
}
add_filter( 'the_content_more_link', 'remove_more_link_scroll' );
?>
```

[Prevent Page Scroll When Clicking the More Link](http://codex.wordpress.org/Customizing_the_Read_More#Prevent_Page_Scroll_When_Clicking_the_More_Link)

Comment: this isn't working for me, as I mentioned in the question itself

Comment: You do have `<?php` and `?>` in there?

Comment: I feel really stupid now.

Comment: I won't tell anybody ;)